# Install MySQL Database on Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, arm, windows-iot-core

I just installed Windows 10 IoT Core on my Raspberry 3 B+.

I'm planning on working with ASP.NET Core and I also need a database.

Problem is, I don't know what to install.

What target do I select - the common Windows Installer won't work on ARM I guess ?

[MySQL Community Server 8.0.15](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Comment: There isn’t a MySQL compatible binary on that page.  What makes you think there should be?

Comment: @Ramhound so it's not possible to install mysql inside windows 10 IoT Core? -  MySQL runs on ARM if I install Rasbian :/

Comment: There doesn’t appear to be any ARM binary compatible listed on that page.  You would have to compile the binary yourself. [Ubuntu ARM](https://www.mininodes.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-the-ubuntu-arm-server/)

Answer (score 0):

> What target do I select - the common Windows Installer won't work on ARM I guess?

Windows x86/x64 binaries are not compatible with Windows IoT Core.

[image]

Source: https://query.prod.cms.rt.microsoft.com/cms/api/am/binary/RWrHjl

> Problem is, I don't know what to install.

Oracle does not provide a binary compatible with Windows IoT at this time.

While not provided directly by Oracle ARM Linux compatibly does seem to exist.